# Use query phrase interpretation to compute a math equation

Tags: python, html

I am using python and html to build a webpage where I can enter a math equation in a textbox and compute the math equation like google calculator. 
Are there any libraries or suggestions as to how I may go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [sympy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy)

```
from sympy import sympify, Symbol
>>> sympify('2 ^ 3').evalf()
8
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> sympify('x ^ 2').evalf(subs={x: 2})
4
```

Comment: How do you install it?